# Itemwriter output using same order that itemreader used to read file

Tags: spring-batch

We have a springbatch job that reads a file (flatfileitemreader), process it and writes data to a queue (jmsitemwriter).

We have another job that reads the queue (jmsitemreader) and writes a file (flatfileitemwriter). It's asynchronous process (in between the execution of the two jobs, we have some manual process that must be performed).

The flat file content doesn't have a line identifier. And we use a multi-threaded approach when reading the file ("throttle-limit"). So, the messages queued do not maintain the same order that they used to have into the flat file.

The problem is that we should generate an output file respecting the original order. So the line 33 inside the incoming file, should be line 33 into the outgoing file (it will have the contents of the original line, plus some data).

Does springbatch provide "native" a way to order the output, respecting the original read order? I used "native" because one solution that we thought is to create an additional step just to add a line number to the file and use it at the end, but I was wondering if this "reinvent the wheel"...

We are using SB 3.0.3

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case you are describing asks that you maintain order across multiple jobs which is not supported.  In theory (while not guaranteed) a single, single threaded step would retain the order of the input file.

Since you are reading in a multithreaded manor, there really isn't a good way to guarantee the order of the items as they are being read.  The best you could do is synchronize the read method and add an id as the items are being read.  If the bottleneck you're attempting to address with multithreading is in the processor or writer, this may not be a bad option.